# Synchronizing bidirectional entities in hibernate jpa spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Trying to understand synchronization of bidirectional entities.
ref: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/

Lets see example of OneToMany bidirectional association.

[image]
See entity class

```java
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
 
    public void addComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
        comment.setPost(this);
    }
 
    public void removeComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
        comment.setPost(null);
    }
}
```

should we call these methods(addComment,removeComment) on managed or transient entities? I am assuming when we just create objects in memory which are transient, it will be a good practice.

If both, is true.
I also saw one article where for synchronizing both side, for parent entity aka Post,had additional method which removes all comments for given post

Service layer

```java
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAllCommentsOfPost() {
        Author author = postRepository.findByName("Joana Nimar");
        post.removeComments(); // use removeComments() helper    
    }
```

Post entity has following

```java
...
... entity code

    public void removeComments() {
        //TODO can be optimized, as it fires single delete queries.
        System.out.println("iterating removeComments");
        Iterator<Comment> iterator = this.comments.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Comment comment = iterator.next();

            comment.setPost(null);
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
...
...
```

But problem here is that, since this is a managed entity, it will fire individual delete statements for each post. Instead better would be to have something like single statement with IN clause to delete entities.

I am not sure what would be correct way.
I see following option:
create another method in repository layer which deletes using jpql.

But, here will entities get synchronized post transaction commit is my query.

I would like to know what are best practices for bidirectional entities.

Comment: What in the heck are you talking about?

Comment: please see https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/ for more idea.